ethernet eth0: TX ring dump
When reading the syslog, I found that NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (fec): transmit queue 0 timed out appeared once. After that, fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: TX ring dump appeared multiple times at intervals ranging from minutes to hour.
The actual problem is that I am creating a socket and sending a data packet via that socket. This socket is added to a thread. Whenever I get the message "ethernet eth0: TX ring dump error," my thread is unable to send data, after 2 to 3 minutes, the thread goes to be in a blocked state(not even the logs are printed). When the "ethernet eth0: TX ring dump" came again , it resumes sending data and going down again after 2-3 minutes . There are no thread locks or unlocks in my code, and I am unsure how to approach this issue.
syslog for reference
Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.971831] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (fec): transmit queue 0 timed out

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.971837] Modules linked in: caam_jr caamhash_desc caamalg_desc authenc libdes imx_thermal snd_soc_fsl_asoc_card snd_ac97_codec imx6_media_csi(C) egalax_ts nvmem_imx_ocotp ftdi_sio usbserial mux_mmio video_mux mux_core caam rtc_snvs nvmem_snvs_lpgpr imx_sdma error virt_dma spi_imx snd_soc_fsl_asrc spi_bitbang coda_vpu v4l2_jpeg imx_vdoa videobuf2_vmalloc dw_hdmi_ahb_audio dw_hdmi_cec imx6_media(C) gpio_keys uio_pdrv_genirq imx_media_common(C) uio sch_fq_codel algif_aead algif_rng algif_skcipher algif_hash af_alg ip_tables x_tables autofs4

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972024] CPU: 2 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/2 Tainted: G WC 5.4.45-g334256aa8a89 #10

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972033] Hardware name: Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (Device Tree)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972043] Backtrace:

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972079] [<c010f49c>] (dump_backtrace) from [<c010f83c>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972099] r7:000001c0 r6:60000113 r5:00000000 r4:c139efa4

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972126] [<c010f81c>] (show_stack) from [<c0cb9f54>] (dump_stack+0xc8/0xdc)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972155] [<c0cb9e8c>] (dump_stack) from [<c012e7bc>] (__warn+0xe0/0x108)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972172] r7:000001c0 r6:00000009 r5:c0b843a8 r4:c10c9b00

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972194] [<c012e6dc>] (__warn) from [<c012ebd0>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0xa4/0xc0)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972209] r7:000001c0 r6:c10c9b00 r5:c1305fc8 r4:c10c9ac4

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972232] [<c012eb30>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<c0b843a8>] (dev_watchdog+0x2fc/0x300)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972251] r9:0001bb58 r8:ffffffff r7:c1304d00 r6:eebec000 r5:eebec2e8 r4:00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972274] [<c0b840ac>] (dev_watchdog) from [<c01c1a60>] (call_timer_fn+0x50/0x1a0)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972291] r8:00000000 r7:c0b840ac r6:00000100 r5:eebec2e8 r4:c13a51c0

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972312] [<c01c1a10>] (call_timer_fn) from [<c01c2d24>] (run_timer_softirq+0x474/0x638)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972331] r9:ef6b4640 r8:00000000 r7:0001bb58 r6:00000000 r5:ee98fd80 r4:eebec2e8

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972357] [<c01c28b0>] (run_timer_softirq) from [<c01024c0>] (__do_softirq+0x158/0x3d4)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972377] r10:ffffe000 r9:00000202 r8:00000100 r7:c13a4e64 r6:00000001 r5:00000002

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972385] r4:c1304084

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972407] [<c0102368>] (__do_softirq) from [<c0135c38>] (irq_exit+0xc0/0xe4)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972426] r10:ef6bb678 r9:f4001100 r8:ee8d7400 r7:00000001 r6:00000000 r5:00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972434] r4:ffffe000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972459] [<c0135b78>] (irq_exit) from [<c01a3c50>] (__handle_domain_irq+0x70/0xc4)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972470] r5:00000000 r4:c12cd254

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972491] [<c01a3be0>] (__handle_domain_irq) from [<c0102324>] (gic_handle_irq+0x5c/0xa0)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972510] r9:f4001100 r8:ee98fea8 r7:f4000100 r6:f400010c r5:c135769c r4:c1306ad0

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972528] [<c01022c8>] (gic_handle_irq) from [<c0101a8c>] (__irq_svc+0x6c/0x90)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972539] Exception stack(0xee98fea8 to 0xee98fef0)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972559] fea0: 00000000 000000af 2e3ef000 00000000 00000000 c130c7f0

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972580] fec0: 000000af 000000af c13a5634 8c376a23 ef6bb678 ee98ff4c ee98fef8 ee98fef8

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972594] fee0: c0a6811c c0a68140 60000013 ffffffff

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972613] r9:ee98e000 r8:c13a5634 r7:ee98fedc r6:ffffffff r5:60000013 r4:c0a68140

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972644] [<c0a67fb8>] (cpuidle_enter_state) from [<c0a6865c>] (cpuidle_enter+0x38/0x48)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972664] r10:c12cc670 r9:c130c7f0 r8:ef6bb678 r7:00000004 r6:00000000 r5:c130c7f0

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972673] r4:ef6bb678

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972700] [<c0a68624>] (cpuidle_enter) from [<c0168324>] (call_cpuidle+0x30/0x48)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972715] r7:00000004 r6:c1306030 r5:c1305fe8 r4:ffffe000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972734] [<c01682f4>] (call_cpuidle) from [<c01687b4>] (do_idle+0x25c/0x2b8)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972754] [<c0168558>] (do_idle) from [<c0168af8>] (cpu_startup_entry+0x28/0x30)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972774] r10:00000000 r9:412fc09a r8:1000406a r7:c13ca0d8 r6:10c0387d r5:00000002

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972782] r4:0000008a

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972810] [<c0168ad0>] (cpu_startup_entry) from [<c0111d80>] (secondary_start_kernel+0x13c/0x160)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972832] [<c0111c44>] (secondary_start_kernel) from [<101027cc>] (0x101027cc)

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972844] r5:00000051 r4:3e98006a

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972897] ---[ end trace a293c2f4e570c3c4 ]---

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972923] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: TX ring dump

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972931] Nr SC addr len SKB

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972946] 0 0x1c00 0x00000000 126 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972959] 1 0x1c00 0x00000000 42 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972971] 2 0x1c00 0x00000000 126 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972982] 3 0x1c00 0x00000000 42 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.972994] 4 0x1c00 0x00000000 126 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.973006] 5 0x1c00 0x00000000 42 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.973016] 6 0x1c00 0x00000000 126 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.973026] 7 0x1c00 0x00000000 42 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.973037] 8 0x1c00 0x00000000 126 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.973047] 9 0x1c00 0x00000000 42 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.973057] 10 0x1c00 0x00000000 126 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.973068] 11 0x1c00 0x00000000 42 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.973078] 12 0x1c00 0x00000000 126 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.973089] 13 0x1c00 0x00000000 42 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.973099] 14 0x1c00 0x00000000 126 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.973109] 15 0x1c00 0x00000000 42 00000000

Oct 6 04:45:34 focal-ventana kernel: [ 753.973121] 16 0x1c00 0x00000000 126 00000000

my kernel version is 5.4.45-g334256aa8a89
Can anyone help me with this?
